# Express race condition during GET

Tags: angular, express

I'm working on an Angular/Node/Express/Psql application. For part of the application I have GET requests going to Express to retrieve users profiles. I have a folder called profile-pics that contains the pictures of the users, if the users picture doesn't exist yet it will retrieve it from the database and inserts it into the folder and the returns the picture.

The current way the GET url request is set up is by a call like this:

```
user/profile-pic?username=bar123456
```

It hits the express route and some of the calls will return the same profile picture even though two different ones are being requested.

So for example the two GET requests will be run

```
user/profile-pic?username=foo123456
user/profile-pic?username=bar123456
```

However both pictures will be of bar123456 picture.

I've tried debugging it by writing

```
console.log('Sending back picture ' + profilePicPath).
```

When I do so I will get

```
'Sending back picture bar123456'
'Sending back picture bar123456'
```

This is the route in express that is returning the picture. I took out the database call as both profile pictures already

```
userRouter.get('/user/profile-pic', function (req, res) {
    let userName = req.query.username;
    fileName = './profile-pics/' + userName + '.jpg';
    userProfilePic = userName + '.jpg';

    fs.exists(fileName, function (exists) {
        if (exists) {            
            console.log('Sending back picture ' + userProfilePic);
            res.status(200).contentType('image/png').sendFile(userProfilePic, {
                root: path.join(__dirname, '../profile-pics/')
            }, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

I've also tried slicing the string to create a new copy because I thought it might have just been copying a reference and the reference got changed. However that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly declare your `fileName` and `userProfilePic` variables as local variables.  When you don't declare them as local, they become implicit globals and they get "shared" among different requests which can easily lead to race conditions as one request handler overwrites the values another request handler is in the middle of using.  Change to this:

```
userRouter.get('/user/profile-pic', function (req, res) {
    let userName = req.query.username;
    let fileName = './profile-pics/' + userName + '.jpg';
    let userProfilePic = userName + '.jpg';

    fs.exists(fileName, function (exists) {
        if (exists) {            
            console.log('Sending back picture ' + userProfilePic);
            res.status(200).contentType('image/png').sendFile(userProfilePic, {
                root: path.join(__dirname, '../profile-pics/')
            }, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

P.S. You also need to send a response in all code paths, such as if the file does not exist or in your error handler.  All paths through a route handler should either call `next()` or send a response themselves.

FYI, running your code through a linter and/or running your code in strict mode will make these programming errors more obvious.